# How does referencing work when have two .c files with global variables of same symbols but different types?

Tags: c, linker, global-variables

**C**

Say I have the following C modules:

MODULE 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x;
int main(){
  foo();
  printf("%i\n",x);
  return 0;
}
```

MODULE 2

```
double x;
void foo(){
  x = 3.14;
}
```

My question is: what does the linker do in this case? In the textbook I'm reading it says the compiler chooses only one of two weak global variables for the linker symbol table. Which of these two is chosen? Or are both chosen? If so, why? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C says it is undefined behavior.

> (C99, 6.9p5) "If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression (other than as part of the operand of a sizeof operator whose result is an integer constant), somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than one"

Being undefined behavior means a linker can abort the linking process in presence of multiple external object definitions.

Now linkers are nice (or *evil*, you can choose) and usually have default extensions to handle multiple external object definitions and not fail in some cases.

If you are using `gcc` and `ld` from binutils, you'll get an error if your two object are explicitly initialized. For example, you have `int x = 0;` in the first translation unit and `double x = 0.0;`.

Otherwise, if one of the external object is not explicitly initialized (the situation in your example) `gcc` will silently combine the two objects into one symbol. You can still ask the linker to report a warning by passing it the option `--warn-common`.

For example when linking the modules:

`gcc -Wl,--warn-common module1.o module2.o`

To get the linking process aborted, you can request the linker to treat all warnings as errors using `--fatal-warnings` option (`-Wl,--fatal-warnings,--warn-common`).

Another way to get the linking process aborted is to use `-fno-common` compiler option, as explained by [@teppic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1627348/teppic) in his answer. `-fno-common` forbids the external objects to get a Common symbol type at compilation. If you do it for both module and then link, you'll also get the multiple definition linker error.

`gcc -Wall -fno-common -c module1.c module2.c`

`gcc module1.o module2.o`

Comment: So, in this case there is only one 'x' in the symbol table? I can see some weird bugs resulting from that. Thx

Comment: @amorimluc in your case chances you'll like get an error from the linker or a single object in the final binary and your program will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: I thought I would, but it compiles and links fine. And x is printed as an int but with the bit-pattern of the 3.14 float. This probably doesn't happen much in real life, but it'd sure be hard to find this subtle bug in a large program...

Comment: @amorimluc it is undefined behavior. A linker can refuse your program. Your linker decided to accept it as an extension and its strategy could be to have one object in the final binary room for the bigger object (`double` here).

Comment: Makes sense, my version of gcc apparently accepts undefined behavior.

Comment: It's not an issue of "accepting" undefined behavior.  It's broken code, and you need to fix it.  Gcc could have a minor update in a few days, and suddenly it would do something completely different.

Comment: @RandyHoward - it's not compliant with ISO C, but that doesn't mean that implementations don't support it (and thus a lot of existing code rely on it). Something that's well documented as a compiler _default_ wouldn't change in a minor update. That said, there's no justification to write code like this, so I agree with you there.

Answer (score 1):

If the implementation supports multiple external definitions, you'll end up with one object that's effectively cast to each type in each module, as in some kind of implicit union variable. The amount of memory for the larger type will be allocated, and both will behave as external declarations.

If you compile using clang or gcc, use the option `-fno-common` to cause an error for this.

Here's the section from the gcc manual:

```
       In C code, controls the placement of uninitialized global
       variables.  Unix C compilers have traditionally permitted multiple
       definitions of such variables in different compilation units by
       placing the variables in a common block.  This is the behavior
       specified by -fcommon, and is the default for GCC on most targets.
       On the other hand, this behavior is not required by ISO C, and on
       some targets may carry a speed or code size penalty on variable
       references.  The -fno-common option specifies that the compiler
       should place uninitialized global variables in the data section of
       the object file, rather than generating them as common blocks.
       This has the effect that if the same variable is declared (without
       "extern") in two different compilations, you will get a multiple-
       definition error when you link them.
```

This option effectively enforces strict ISO C compliance with respect to multiple definitions.

This behaviour is generally accepted for external variables of the *same* type. As the GCC manual states, most compilers support this, and (providing the types are the same), the C99 standard defines its use as an extension.